How to solve the following system?
Consider the system
eqs = {Derivative[1][n\[Mu]][
   t] == -(1.3843805755399188*^23*n\[Mu][t]*n\[Mu]bar[t]) - 
       454545.45454545453*n\[Mu][t] + 
   5.074742843065546*^-7/E^(33.333333333333336*t), 
   Derivative[1][n\[Mu]bar][
   t] == -(1.3843805755399188*^23*n\[Mu][t]*n\[Mu]bar[t]) - 
       454545.45454545453*n\[Mu]bar[t] + 
   5.074742843065546*^-7/E^(33.333333333333336*t), 
   n\[Mu][0.001] == 0, n\[Mu]bar[0.001] == 0};

I am trying to solve it:
sol = NDSolve[eqs, {n\[Mu][t], 
   n\[Mu]bar[t]}, {t, 0.001,3}][[1]]

But it appears to be non-adequate because the solution may become negative.
Could you please tell me how to improve NDSolve to get a stable solution?

Mathematica v12.2 shows several messages when executing NDSolve, did you see these messages too?

Did you already think about the scaling of your odes?

@UlrichNeumann : I fixed the minimal time in NDSolve.

@UlrichNeumann : It did not work (I tried with SCALE = 10^10).

Your ODEs are identical, aren't they?

@user64494 : indeed, you are right. So it seems I may convert it to a single equation where n\[Mu][t]*n\[Mu]bar[t] is replaced with n\[Mu][t]^2. However, it is then still negative, which is not expected from some grounding.

Your ODEs are identical. The following works.
eqs = {Derivative[1][n\[Mu]][
t] == -(1.3843805755399188*^23*n\[Mu][t]*n\[Mu]bar[t]) - 
454545.45454545453*n\[Mu][t] + 
5.074742843065546*^-7/E^(33.333333333333336*t), 
  Derivative[1][n\[Mu]bar][
t] == -(1.3843805755399188*^23*n\[Mu][t]*n\[Mu]bar[t]) - 
454545.45454545453*n\[Mu]bar[t] + 
5.074742843065546*^-7/E^(33.333333333333336*t), 
  n\[Mu][0.001] == 0, n\[Mu]bar[0.001] == 0};
sol = NDSolve[Rationalize[eqs, 0], {n\[Mu][t], n\[Mu]bar[t]}, 
{t, 0.001, 0.002}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
Plot[Evaluate[n\[Mu]bar[t] /. sol], {t, 0.001, 0.002}]


DSolve[{Derivative[1][n\[Mu]][t] ==      5.074742843065546*^-7  E^(-33.333333333333336 t) -       454545.45454545453 n\[Mu][t] -       1.3843805755399188*^23  n\[Mu][t]^2 , n\[Mu][0.001] == 0},    n\[Mu][t], t] // Chop produces the "exact" solution {{n\[Mu][t] -> 0}}.
